# Selenium Python How to determine if a dynamic drop-down list is fully loaded?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Example: To wait for

```
<select id="myselect"></select>
```

to be populated with

```
<option value="123">One-two-three</option>
<option value="abc">ABC</option>
             ...
```

I asked this kind of question before, however, this time, I have a more complicated situation:

> I don't know what their option values are;  I don't know how many of them will be populated;

For this kind of situation, is it `time.sleep()` the best approach?

Comment: What is the use case here, are you trying to wait for the element and then proceed with your flow?

Comment: @michael satish I will be waiting for all the option loaded and store them into a list. Then use select_by_visible_text() to select each element in the list to load a page one at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be sure, you'd need some sort of known information, such as what the last option would be or how many in total you expect. Otherwise, you are essentially making an assumption that it's done. If some sort of delay occurs that causes an element to appear late, you might miss it.

You could count the number, sleep, then count the number again and see if there's a change. If not, that would indicate you're done, but again, delays could still occur.

Comment: Thanks. I think I would be counting the option twice.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know Python (I use Java), so I cannot help you with the syntax.

You can use FluentWait to count the number of options twice, several milliseconds apart. If the counts match, you're good to go.

Comment: Counting the options twice is a good idea. I will work on that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another option may be available to you if your web server has a public API that would retrieve the full list of options that should appear in the dropdown.  You would then be able to make an api request to get the list of options that should display in the menu without having to actually look at the menu.

your test of each menu option can proceed, waiting for each target menu item as necessary.